# Easy and simple GUI source version control on Windows

Tags: software-development, gui, programming, version-control, mercurial

I'm a programmer and want begin a work with source version control systems.

Of course I know about Git and its popularity. I tried to work with it (its clients) several times, but I did't like it. The fact that I have the following considerations about programs: I am convinced that all the basic operations should be simple. It seems to me that if the main basics and common operations are hard to find or don't work on the first try, then it's a bad program.

I've read some articles where it is said that the Mercurial is the best choice in this situation. I tried some clients (SmartGit, SourceTree, TortoiseHg, EasyMercurial), but still have not find such a program that would have a good interface and easy acces to basic operations.

So, I need a simple GUI source version control system. Simplicity and clarity are the most important (may or may not be Mercurial).

Comment: What do expect when saying simple? What don't you like in detail?

Comment: I find the GitHub client to be quite simple.

Comment: For simplcity, and the best GUI around, you can't beat  https://www.plasticscm.com/

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) with the [Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) client on Windows for many years and find it very easy to use.  The client is implemented as a Shell extension (on the context menu) and can be integrated into Visual Studio if that's your IDE.

[image: SVN Context menu]

[image: Client commit dialog]

Subversion is free to use and provides command line access if needed.